# Custom JSON data decode using Swift 4 JSONDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy.custom(_:)

Tags: json, swift4

I'm looking for example for JSON custom strategy Data decode with:

```
JSONDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy.custom(_:)
```

Does someone has example or link(s) about? [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datadecodingstrategy/custom?fbclid=IwAR162fK3enhfK-8qqSW8PGUT8hbr6FrOXGf3WWsrhmXQ4Mh9VcyXfNnSHeo) doesn't explain too much about.

Thank you very much!

Francesco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a more comprehensive example of custom data encoding and decoding strategy. Let's start with a very simple data model:

```
struct Model: Codable {
    var data: Data
}
```

### Encoding

`Data` in Swift is encoded into a string in JSON. The default encoding use Base64 so if you assign `data` to the bytes that make up the string "Hello world", you will get the following data:

```
let m = Model(data: "Hello world".data(using: .utf8)!)
let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(m)
let jsonString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!

print(jsonString) // {"data":"SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="}
```

But let's say you want to use hex codes instead of Base64. You can write your custom data encoding function:

```
func customDataEncoder(data: Data, encoder: Encoder) throws {
    let str = (0..<data.count).map {
        String(data[$0], radix: 16, uppercase: true)
    }.joined(separator: " ")

    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try container.encode(str)
}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dataEncodingStrategy = .custom(customDataEncoder)

let m = Model(data: "Hello world".data(using: .utf8)!)
let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(m)
let jsonString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!

print(jsonString) // {"data":"48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64"}
```

### Decoding

Decoding is the process of turning a JSON string to `Data` in Swift. If the string was Base64-encoded, you don't need to do anything else. But since we encoded our `Data` in hex, you need to provide a custom data decoder:

```
func customDataDecoder(decoder: Decoder) throws -> Data {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let str = try container.decode(String.self)

    let bytes = str.components(separatedBy: " ").map {
        UInt8($0, radix: 16)!
    }
    return Data(bytes)
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .custom(customDataDecoder)

let decodedM = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: json)
print(m.data == decodedM.data) // true
```

**Notes:** when I say "`Data` in Swift is encoded into a string in JSON", it is true most of the times but does not have to be so every time. Nothing prevents you  from encoding the property `data` into something like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "count": 11,
        "string": "Hello world",
        "hex": "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64"
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to update the custom decoder to match the JSON format.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! :-D